# Remove the [organization] tag

Tags: support, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

A quick look seems to suggest that this tag is meta, and that we could just remove it and leave not much of a trace. Looking at [organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/organization), I see many questions. Some are, modernly speaking, too subjective or off-topic, but most would just be perfectly well off without the tag.

One of my bug-bears is the existence of bad tags that facilitate bad questions. I have this forlorn hope that if a new user doesn't find some tag in the list of available tags, it might cause them to stop and think about the question.

Now we have 800 questions in the tag.

Comment: Well, if they're too subjective or off topic, it's probably worth going through them instead of doing a bulk removal, no?

Comment: I am going through them, voting to close as appropriate. I don't know how likely we are to attract enough attention to actually get them closed.

Comment: @Rosinante As always, flag if you feel the close vote velocity isn't there.  Probably excessive, but copy paste a link to this meta post and we'll get to those, as those don't decay.

Answer (score 9):

I agree that [organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/organization) doesn't add much to the questions, and it would probably be better to remove it.

In the questions I read, the tag is used to mean different things, such as "the question is about how to organize the data I have," "the question is about how to organize the scripts I have," or "the question is about an organization's data I am handling with a CRM."

As you said, there are questions that are off-topic, or too subjective. It is better to first close those questions, and then take care of the tag itself. Differently, once the tag is removed, it would be difficult to find which questions should have been closed.

Comment: Personally questions about how to organise things seem more Programmers-related.

Comment: ...but rather opinion based which is off-topic. So yeah, the tag should be removed